# Design of the two stage amplifier with p-type input

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, analog, schematics, cmos

I have to design the two stage amplifier with **p-type input** (p-type diff pair), the schematic bellow:

[image]

However, mostly tutorials discuss the same architecture but with **n-type input**.

[image]

My main questions: **Can I use tutorials with the n-type input stage amplifier for designing my amplifier with the p-type input stage?**

Secondly, can you recommend papers there design of the "p-type" architecture is shown, which I can use for my design?

Lastly, what is the difference between these two architectures?(in general)

Regards,
Paddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can regard both types as **complementary**, if the circuits are identical but one is just the "upside down" version of the other, **everything applies to both architectures** you only need to watch the directions of currents and voltage polarties but that is it.

*Lastly, what is the difference between these two architectures?(in general)*

They are identical but one is just the "upside down" version of the other.
Think about this for a while and you'll see that they're the same architecture wise. The only reason for using the P-input stage instead of the N-input stage is the (commonmode) voltage range of the input voltages. But that is a property of the circuit. If one has an input voltage range of 2 V to Vdd, the other will have an input voltage range of Vss to (Vdd - 2 V) (assuming all NMOS and PMOS are completely complementary).